# Error connect to informix with PDO

Tags: php, pdo, informix

i try connect to informix

```
try {
$db = new PDO("informix:host=IP; service=0000;
    database=some_db; server=someshop; protocol=onsoctcp;
    EnableScrollableCursors=1", "login", "pass");

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

and i get PDOException
SQLDriverConnect: -11005

why? someone faced with this error? and how to fix it?

Comment: What kind of database are you trying to access?

Answer (score 0):

Please find informix's port number and enter that as "service=****"(without quotes) , where **** is the port number. If you tell your OS name, I tell you how to find informix's port number.